# How to insert text read strings into specific variables

Tags: java, string, text-files, bufferedreader, filereader

I am having issues inserting each line of the simple textfile into a specific variable I want it to go to. For example my text file is ordered like this (no spaces in the text file between the strings just this editor would put them all together)

> Dallas
>
> 78 F
>
> North, 15 mph
>
> dallasimage
>
> Denver
>
> 29 F
>
> South, 10 mph
>
> denverimage

and I want  Dallas in city variable, 78f in temperature variable, and so on until text ends, at the moment is all goes into city variable, it all prints from there! I know scanner has a next line but never used it before so I got stuck here.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Textreader {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
                        String city ="a";
                        String temp ="b";
                        String wind ="c";
                        String image = "d";
            File file = new File("load.txt");
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                              city = stringBuffer.append(line).toString();
                              stringBuffer.append("\n");
                               //city = line.toString();
                               temp = stringBuffer.append(line).toString();
                                wind  = line;
                                image = line;
                //stringBuffer.append(line);
                //stringBuffer.append("\n");
            }
            fileReader.close();
            System.out.println("Contents of file:");
                        System.out.println(city);
                        System.out.println(temp);
                        
            //System.out.println(stringBuffer.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue comes with the fact that your variable "line" is not changing his content and repeated in all your variables. Read all your lines into a collection or array and then proceeed. Something like this:

```
    int count = 0;
    String[] lines = new String[4];
    String line;
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        lines[counter++] = line;
    }

    city = lines[0];
    temp = lines[1];
    // ....
```

Comment: I did this approach and instead it did increment but everything it kept read the previous line and including it. For example for line[1] , it read Dallas, 78 f, for line[2] it read Dallas, 78F North , 15mph

Comment: Hi, my bad. Went too quickly on this one.  I corrected the code.  This is a simple example and not the best way to approach it.  Still, it would do the job for you.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `bufferedReader.readLine()` to retrieve the next line.

```
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    city = line;
    temp = bufferedReader.readLine();
    wind = bufferedReader.readLine();
    image = bufferedReader.readLine();
}
```

Comment: Did I have to convert them using to string which I tried as well but all returned null.

Answer (score 0):

Check out java.util.Scanner class. You can do something like this with it:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(file);
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.+?)\n(.+?)\n(.+?)\n(.+?)\n");
while(s.findWithinHorizon(pattern, 0) != null) {
  MatchResult result = s.match();
  city = result.group(1); 
  temp = result.group(2);
  wind = result.group(3);
  img  = result.group(4);
  // etc. (Note that the next pass through the loop will override these variables 
  // so, unless you save the values somewhere, you will end up with them holding last
  // entry from your file once the loop is done. 
}
```

Comment: I have to use buffered reader for further in the program and all the above suggestions did not help.

Comment: Nah, you can't use the same reader "later in the program", because  you'd have read everything from it by then anyway. If something " did not" help, it probably means you misunderstood or used it wrong. If you want more help, gotta provide more info than "it doesn't help" ... And show your work.